# Utilization imbalance in Storm Bolt Executors

Tags: performance, apache-storm

I am running the Rolling Count Benchmark from this [set of benchmarks](https://github.com/intel-hadoop/storm-benchmark). Here is the relevant piece of code:

```
spout = new FileReadSpout(BenchmarkUtils.ifAckEnabled(config));

TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

builder.setSpout(SPOUT_ID, spout, spoutNum);
builder.setBolt(SPLIT_ID, new WordCount.SplitSentence(), spBoltNum)
        .localOrShuffleGrouping(SPOUT_ID);
builder.setBolt(COUNTER_ID, new RollingCountBolt(windowLength, emitFreq), rcBoltNum)
        .fieldsGrouping(SPLIT_ID, new Fields(WordCount.SplitSentence.FIELDS));
```

I have a three node setup with a total of 96 cores with `spBoltNum = 6` and `rcBoltNum = 6`. After a run, I see that there is a significant imbalance in the capacity metric reported for each executor of the split bolt. Even though each node has 2 executors for split bolt. I see the following numbers for capacity:

For split bolt executors on

Node 1 ~ 0.95

Node 2 ~ 0.7

Node 3 ~ 0.25

I do not understand this imbalance in utilization as the grouping for split bolt is localOrShuffleGrouping, I was expecting the capacity reported for each executor to be more or less equal. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

What is your `spoutNum`? A would assume it is `1` as `FileReaderSpout` read a local file (if I am not mistaken).

As your split-bolt connect to the spout via `localOrShuffle` some instances will be node-local to `FileReaderSpout` and some remote. `localOrShuffle` prefers to send to the local instance and only send over the network in case of an overload of the local consumer. Thus, your local split bolt executor get much more data than the remote one.

Comment: Yes, if only one spout is working that would certainly be the case. I have set spout executors to a multiple of 3 as well. I am under the impression that storm packages the local resource i.e., a file in this case when the topology is submitted and deployed on multiple nodes. Perhaps I am wrong.

Comment: I checked the number of tuples emitted by the executors of spout on other node and it appears that they are emitting almost the same amount of tuples.

Comment: It actually ended up being the result of interference from external factors.